# How to download multiple documents(word,ppt,pdf) on single click using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have developed one web application using java. i want to download multiple documents (include word, ppt, pdf) on single click in browser using javascript.. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have tried so far and the specific issues you face

Comment: No need for JS. Zip the files on the server and add an HTML link to the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Call a function at `onclick` and execute this :

```
window.location.href = 'file.doc';
window.location.href = 'file.ppt';
```